# WIFI Direct ( Wifi p2p) disconnection autometically after 10 second

Tags: wifi-direct, p2p

I'm trying to connect android and Raspberry PI using WIFI Direct. It is connected successfully but it's the disconnect after 10 seconds automatically.

My configuration file is as per below

**/etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf**

```
ctrl_interface=/var/run/wpa_supplicant

country=IN
ap_scan=1
device_name=rasberry
device_type=1-0050F204-1
driver_param=use_p2p_group_interface=1
p2p_go_intent=15
p2p_go_ht40=1
p2p_listen_reg_class=81
p2p_listen_channel=1
p2p_oper_reg_class=81
p2p_oper_channel=1


network={
        ssid="DIRECT-Ke"
        bssid=52:6d:c8:0d:bf:4c
        psk="Y2s38gWz"
        proto=RSN
        key_mgmt=WPA-PSK
        pairwise=CCMP
        auth_alg=OPEN
        mode=3
        disabled=2
}

network={
        ssid="DIRECT-Wx"
        bssid=62:cf:4f:8d:2d:d0
        psk="rm9CdjHH"
        proto=RSN
        key_mgmt=WPA-PSK
        pairwise=CCMP
        auth_alg=OPEN
        mode=3
        disabled=2
}

network={
        ssid="DIRECT-ZY"
        bssid=66:38:5e:c6:c0:38
        psk="nR5wfpTa"
        proto=RSN
        key_mgmt=WPA-PSK
        pairwise=CCMP
        auth_alg=OPEN
        mode=3
        disabled=2
}
```

**My Commands are as per below.**

```
 root@raspberrypi:/home/pi# 
root@raspberrypi:/home/pi# pkill wpa_supplicant
root@raspberrypi:/home/pi# 
root@raspberrypi:/home/pi# 
root@raspberrypi:/home/pi# wpa_supplicant -B -iwlan0 -Dnl80211 -c /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf
Successfully initialized wpa_supplicant
root@raspberrypi:/home/pi# wpa_cli -iwlan0 p2p_group_add persistent
OK
root@raspberrypi:/home/pi# ifconfig
eth0: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        ether b8:27:eb:98:b2:af  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

p2p-wlan0-0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet6 fe80::7afe:3a80:7306:daac  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether aa:5c:a2:ac:60:88  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 13  bytes 2236 (2.1 KiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

wlan0: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        ether b8:27:eb:cd:e7:fa  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0


root@raspberrypi:/home/pi# 
root@raspberrypi:/home/pi# wpa_cli -ip2p-wlan0-0 wps_pin any 0000
0000root@raspberrypi:/home/pi# 
root@raspberrypi:/home/pi# 
root@raspberrypi:/home/pi# 
root@raspberrypi:/home/pi# wpa_cli 
wpa_cli v2.8-devel
Copyright (c) 2004-2019, Jouni Malinen <j@w1.fi> and contributors

This software may be distributed under the terms of the BSD license.
See README for more details.


Selected interface 'p2p-wlan0-0'

Interactive mode

<3>RX-PROBE-REQUEST sa=8a:a3:03:ae:de:ff signal=0
<3>RX-PROBE-REQUEST sa=8a:a3:03:ae:de:ff signal=0
<3>RX-PROBE-REQUEST sa=8a:a3:03:ae:de:ff signal=0
<3>RX-PROBE-REQUEST sa=8a:a3:03:ae:de:ff signal=0
<3>RX-PROBE-REQUEST sa=8a:a3:03:ae:de:ff signal=0
<3>RX-PROBE-REQUEST sa=8a:a3:03:ae:de:ff signal=0
<3>WPS-ENROLLEE-SEEN 16:ad:ad:44:6d:08 52069f7c-c906-589a-8745-74c79d7d0d35 0-00000000-0 0x3148 0 1 [ ]
<3>RX-PROBE-REQUEST sa=16:ad:ad:44:6d:08 signal=0
<3>WPS-ENROLLEE-SEEN 16:ad:ad:44:6d:08 52069f7c-c906-589a-8745-74c79d7d0d35 0-00000000-0 0x3148 0 1 [ ]
<3>RX-PROBE-REQUEST sa=16:ad:ad:44:6d:08 signal=0
<3>WPS-ENROLLEE-SEEN 16:ad:ad:44:6d:08 52069f7c-c906-589a-8745-74c79d7d0d35 0-00000000-0 0x3148 0 1 [ ]
<3>RX-PROBE-REQUEST sa=16:ad:ad:44:6d:08 signal=0
<3>CTRL-EVENT-SUBNET-STATUS-UPDATE status=0
<3>CTRL-EVENT-EAP-STARTED 8a:a3:03:ae:5e:ff
<3>CTRL-EVENT-EAP-PROPOSED-METHOD vendor=0 method=1
<3>CTRL-EVENT-EAP-PROPOSED-METHOD vendor=14122 method=254
<3>WPS-REG-SUCCESS 8a:a3:03:ae:5e:ff 52069f7c-c906-589a-8745-74c79d7d0d35
<3>WPS-SUCCESS 
<3>CTRL-EVENT-EAP-FAILURE 8a:a3:03:ae:5e:ff
<3>CTRL-EVENT-SUBNET-STATUS-UPDATE status=0
<3>AP-STA-CONNECTED 8a:a3:03:ae:5e:ff p2p_dev_addr=8a:a3:03:ae:de:ff
> p2p_peers
8a:a3:03:ae:de:ff
> 
> 
> 
> 
> status
bssid=aa:5c:a2:ac:60:88
freq=2412
ssid=DIRECT-NU
id=0
mode=P2P GO
pairwise_cipher=CCMP
group_cipher=CCMP
key_mgmt=WPA2-PSK
wpa_state=COMPLETED
ip_address=169.254.68.39
p2p_device_address=aa:5c:a2:ac:e0:88
address=aa:5c:a2:ac:60:88
uuid=a745cd13-965d-5f14-ba81-c7e7e99f8391
<3>AP-STA-DISCONNECTED 8a:a3:03:ae:5e:ff p2p_dev_addr=8a:a3:03:ae:de:ff
<3>RX-PROBE-REQUEST sa=8a:a3:03:ae:de:ff signal=0
<3>RX-PROBE-REQUEST sa=8a:a3:03:ae:de:ff signal=0
<3>RX-PROBE-REQUEST sa=8a:a3:03:ae:de:ff signal=0
```

**Requested-Log of wpa_supplicant  Connection creation and disconnected**

```
AP-STA-CONNECTED fe:31:25:c7:57:0b p2p_dev_addr=fe:31:25:c7:57:0b
nl80211: Set STA flags - ifname=p2p-wlan0-0 addr=fe:31:25:c7:57:0b total_flags=0x61 flags_or=0x1 flags_and=0xffffffff authorized=1
hostapd_logger: STA fe:31:25:c7:57:0b - authorizing port
hostapd_logger: STA fe:31:25:c7:57:0b - pairwise key handshake completed (RSN)
EAPOL: disable timer tick
P2P: Expiring old peer entry fa:d0:27:39:c8:98
P2P-DEVICE-LOST p2p_dev_addr=fa:d0:27:39:c8:98
p2p-wlan0-0: Control interface command 'SCAN'
p2p-wlan0-0: Setting scan request: 0.000000 sec
p2p-wlan0-0: Starting AP scan for wildcard SSID
WPS: Building WPS IE for Probe Request
WPS:  * Version (hardcoded 0x10)
WPS:  * Request Type
WPS:  * Config Methods (3148)
WPS:  * UUID-E
WPS:  * Primary Device Type
WPS:  * RF Bands (1)
WPS:  * Association State
WPS:  * Configuration Error (0)
WPS:  * Device Password ID (0)
WPS:  * Manufacturer
WPS:  * Model Name
WPS:  * Model Number
WPS:  * Device Name
WPS:  * Version2 (0x20)
P2P: * P2P IE header
P2P: * Capability dev=25 group=00
P2P: * Listen Channel: Regulatory Class 81 Channel 1
p2p-wlan0-0: Add radio work 'scan'@0xbb6a70
p2p-wlan0-0: First radio work item in the queue - schedule start immediately
p2p-wlan0-0: Starting radio work 'scan'@0xbb6a70 after 0.000086 second wait
p2p-wlan0-0: nl80211: scan request
Scan requested (ret=0) - scan timeout 10 seconds
nl80211: Drv Event 33 (NL80211_CMD_TRIGGER_SCAN) received for p2p-wlan0-0
p2p-wlan0-0: nl80211: Scan trigger
p2p-wlan0-0: Event SCAN_STARTED (46) received
p2p-wlan0-0: Own scan request started a scan in 0.000222 seconds
RTM_NEWLINK: ifi_index=4 ifname=p2p-wlan0-0 wext ifi_family=0 ifi_flags=0x11043 ([UP][RUNNING][LOWER_UP])
nl80211: Drv Event 34 (NL80211_CMD_NEW_SCAN_RESULTS) received for p2p-wlan0-0
p2p-wlan0-0: nl80211: New scan results available
nl80211: Scan probed for SSID ''
nl80211: Scan included frequencies: 2412 2417 2422 2427 2432 2437 2442 2447 2452 2457 2462 2467 2472
p2p-wlan0-0: Event SCAN_RESULTS (3) received
p2p-wlan0-0: Scan completed in 0.807521 seconds
nl80211: Received scan results (2 BSSes)
p2p-wlan0-0: BSS: Start scan result update 1
p2p-wlan0-0: BSS: Add new id 0 BSSID fa:d0:27:39:48:98 SSID 'DIRECT-2739C898' freq 2447
p2p-wlan0-0: BSS: Add new id 1 BSSID 32:cd:a7:c6:e8:09 SSID 'DIRECT-ZzM2070 Series' freq 2412
BSS: last_scan_res_used=2/32
p2p-wlan0-0: Ignore scan results in AP mode
p2p-wlan0-0: Radio work 'scan'@0xbb6a70 done in 0.813949 seconds
p2p-wlan0-0: radio_work_free('scan'@0xbb6a70): num_active_works --> 0
p2p-dev-wlan0: Updating scan results from sibling
nl80211: Received scan results (2 BSSes)
p2p-dev-wlan0: BSS: Start scan result update 151
BSS: last_scan_res_used=2/32
p2p-dev-wlan0: New scan results available (own=0 ext=0)
WPS: AP fa:d0:27:39:48:98 type 0 added
WPS: AP 32:cd:a7:c6:e8:09 type 1 added
WPS: AP[0] fa:d0:27:39:48:98 type=0 tries=0 last_attempt=-1 sec ago blacklist=0
WPS: AP[1] 32:cd:a7:c6:e8:09 type=1 tries=0 last_attempt=-1 sec ago blacklist=0
wlan0: Updating scan results from sibling
nl80211: Received scan results (2 BSSes)
wlan0: BSS: Start scan result update 151
BSS: last_scan_res_used=2/32
wlan0: New scan results available (own=0 ext=0)
WPS: AP fa:d0:27:39:48:98 type 0 added
WPS: AP 32:cd:a7:c6:e8:09 type 1 added
WPS: AP[0] fa:d0:27:39:48:98 type=0 tries=0 last_attempt=-1 sec ago blacklist=0
WPS: AP[1] 32:cd:a7:c6:e8:09 type=1 tries=0 last_attempt=-1 sec ago blacklist=0
wlan0: No suitable network found
nl80211: Drv Event 20 (NL80211_CMD_DEL_STATION) received for p2p-wlan0-0
nl80211: Delete station fe:31:25:c7:57:0b
p2p-wlan0-0: Event DISASSOC (1) received
p2p-wlan0-0: Disassociation notification
p2p-wlan0-0:  * reason 0
p2p-wlan0-0:  * address fe:31:25:c7:57:0b
Disassociation frame IE(s) - hexdump(len=0): [NULL]
hostapd_logger: STA fe:31:25:c7:57:0b - disassociated
p2p-wlan0-0: AP-STA-DISCONNECTED fe:31:25:c7:57:0b p2p_dev_addr=fe:31:25:c7:57:0b
AP-STA-DISCONNECTED fe:31:25:c7:57:0b p2p_dev_addr=fe:31:25:c7:57:0b
hostapd_logger: STA fe:31:25:c7:57:0b - event 2 notification
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is your IP address 169.254.68.39 appropriate with `wpa_cli -i p2p-wlan0-0 status`?

From your *ifconfig* output, the IPv4 addressing appears to be missing for *p2p-wlan0-0* (the P2P-GO persistent group). Check your *systemd-networkd* configuration (if you are using this method) or your *dnsmasq* configuration, so that an IP address is appropriately given to this virtual interface. In general, this is a typical problem producing fast disconnection just after the P2P session is successfully activated.

Example of *systemd-networkd* configuration in a file under */etc/systemd/network/*:

```
[Match]
Name=p2p-wlan0-*
[Network]
Address=192.168.4.1/24
DHCPServer=yes
```

Alternative example of */etc/dnsmasq.conf*:

```
interface=p2p-wlan0-*
dhcp-range=192.168.4.50,192.168.4.199,12h
dhcp-option=3
```

Notice also that you are using a 4-digit PIN. By default, 8-digit PINs are configured.

Answer (score 2):

I do not understand the setup in `/etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf`. For me it looks like a mix up of an [autonomous group owner](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/94693/79866) with a [dynamic negotiated group owner](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/117239/79866). Then with

```
p2p_listen_reg_class=81
p2p_listen_channel=1
p2p_oper_reg_class=81
p2p_oper_channel=1
```

you restricted the communication to use only channel 1 rather than 1, 6 and 11. This is only for debugging. You should not use it for normal operation. I suggest to try to [Connect Android smartphone with Wi-Fi Direct to a Raspberry Pi](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/117239/79866).

Comment: @ino thank you for comment. I follow the steps as per the link mention by you, When I connect it's getting connected but after some time it's automatically getting disconnected.

Comment: @bhavinpanara What connection method do you use? Have you tried default pin code authentication? What messages does wpa_supplicant give you why it stops the connection?

Comment: I have tried with the default pin code authentication method also but the observation is the same. Currently, i have put log of Connect with the pin code method, with pin set by the smartphone method.

Comment: @bhavinpanara What Android version do you use on the smartphone?

Comment: Android version: 10 QP1A.190711.020

Comment: I have also tested with Android version: 8.1.0 and observation are the same that it's disconnected automatically after connected.  And i also check android to the android connection between 8.1.0 and 10 QP1A.190711.020 it's working perfectly. Thank you for your time!

Comment: @ ingo Your guidance into this problem is really help full to me. If you have any idea that I have to try out please share it. Thank you.

Comment: @bhavinpanara Do you start the connection from the beginning? Do you run wpa_supplicant in the foreground with the help of screen? Does the frequencies match? Does the `P2P-PROV-DISC-*-REQ *` message match the pin authentication method? Do you have invited an other Available device?

Comment: @ ingo(1)Yes, I have start connection from the beginning. (2) Yes, I have run wpa_supplicant in the foreground with the help of two screen logs are updated in the question section (3) Frequency match, not sure but from the log found `P2P-GROUP-STARTED p2p-wlan0-0 GO ssid="DIRECT-Q0" freq=2437 go_dev_addr=2e:2c:5b:36:09:20`
(4) Yes It's match. `P2P-PROV-DISC-SHOW-PIN fe:31:25:c7:57:0b 22929280 p2p_dev_addr=fe:31:25:c7:57:0b pri_dev_type=10-0050F204-5 name='Redmi 9i' config_methods=0x188 dev_capab=0x25 group_capab=0x0` (5) Not invite any other device.

Comment: @ ingo did you found anything **wrong**?    Thank you for your time!!

Comment: I*m out of ideas now. The problem is that I can't reproduce it. It's working for me. I cannot look for an error that isn't present. You can try to start wpa_supplicant with the additional option `-d`, means debug. But this gives you a huge amount of additional messages that may more confuse than help. You can try to redirect the output into a file to examine it later, e.g. `sudo /sbin/wpa_supplicant -c/etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant-wlan0.conf -Dnl80211 -iwlan0 -d > debug.out`.

Comment: I have started wpa_supplicant as per your suggested way.  I found log  `nl80211: Drv Event 20 (NL80211_CMD_DEL_STATION) received for p2p-wlan0-0`   This command `NL80211_CMD_DEL_STATION` is responsible for delete connection. but I'm finding it's the reason why this  `NL80211_CMD_DEL_STATION` command is executing in wpa_supplicant.  I have also edited the log in the question section. if you know the reasion please guide me into that.  Thank you for support !!

Comment: @ ingo One more observation is that I can create successful communication **between two Linux machines** using wifi direct. My ultimate goal was to establish communication between Windows 10 and Linux. Here [ https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-hardware/how-to-implement-wifi-direct-between-windows10-and/4ca49250-38a0-4327-9f39-47284a9af800?tm=1585548436542 ]. In windows to Linux have the same observation as android to Linux.  And android to windows is working.  So something I'm missing on the Linux side.

Comment: This does not look like a dynamic negotiated group, because `p2p_connect` is not used. A number of persistent groups are indeed created in the configuration file with different `bssid`, possibly due to [the randomized address issue](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/q/117119/126729) each time *wpa_supplicant* is restarted.